# Three.js: How to match EdgesHelper to Mesh

Tags: javascript, three.js, helper, mesh

In a scene I have added several mesh objects (cubes).  An EdgeHelper has been made for each cube. The cubes move and rotate and the Edgehelpers move and rotate with them.

I would like to change the color of an EdgeHelper when it's associated cube mesh is selected. (The selection method is not important).

So, given a particular cube mesh, how do I find the associated EdgeHelper object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you create an `edgesHelper` for a given `mesh`, all you have to do is add a new property to the mesh:

```
var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( ... );

var edgesHelper = new THREE.EdgesHelper( mesh );

mesh.edgesHelper = edgesHelper;
```

Now you can change the helper color like so:

```
mesh.edgesHelper.material.color.set( 0xff0000 );
```

three.js r.76

Comment: Works great! Thanks very much.  But I wonder how (without using this property trick) does THREE.js keep the position & rotation of any EdgesHelper synched with the position & rotation of its corresponding source "mesh" ?

Comment: Aha, found another of your answers...many helpers have this line of code "this.matrix = object.matrixWorld;" i.e. the edgeHelper uses the matrix of the source mesh object.

Answer (score 1):

When you create meshes and EdgeHelpers you can assign them the same `.name` attribute:

```
mesh0.name = 0;
edgeHelper0.name = 0;

mesh1.name = 1;
edgeHelper1.name = 1;

...and so on

**if you wrap this in a loop even better
```

so when a mesh is selected you can read its `.name`attribute and pick the corresponding edgeHelper.

Comment: Thanks. I can see how this would work.  But it requires a scan/inspection of all edgeHelpers to find the one with .name value matching .name value of a selected mesh.  So I prefer WestLangley's method of assigning the edgeHelper as a property of the mesh.